Deploying Symfony Application with Platform.sh API returns 500 error on POST
I'm new in Symfony and I'm using Platform.sh for the first time.
I want to serve an API built with API Platform. It has a lot entity as api resource and it's running with postgresql.
I want to set DATABASE_URL environment variable using provided variables by Platform.sh from relationships.
I missunderstand how platform.sh processes the .app.platform.yaml file and does it use the .env file because I configured these file like this:
.env file:
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=1
APP_SECRET=5c626ab6e98cb66b5b0e1f9433dffd77

DATABASE_URL="postgresql://app:!ChangeMe!@database:5432/app?serverVersion=15&charset=utf8"

MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=doctrine://default?auto_setup=0

CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN='^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:[0-9]+)?$'

ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200

.app.platform.yaml:
# platform.app.yaml


dependencies:
    php:
        composer/composer: "^2"

runtime:
    extensions:
        - apcu
        - blackfire
        - ctype
        - iconv
        - mbstring
        - pdo_pgsql
        - sodium
        - xsl

    database: "postgresql:postgresql" #servisadıservicesyamldaolan:servis database ise env adı
    #elasticsearch: "elasticsearch:elasticsearch"

variables:
    php:
        opcache.preload: config/preload.php

build:
    flavor: composer

disk: 1024

web:
    locations:
        "/":
            root: "public"
            expires: 1h
            passthru: "/index.php"

mounts:
    "/var": { source: local, source_path: var }

hooks:
    build: |
        set -x -e

        curl -fs https://get.symfony.com/cloud/configurator | bash
        
        NODE_VERSION=18 symfony-build

    deploy: |
        set -x -e

        symfony-deploy
        

crons:
    security-check:
        # Check that no security issues have been found for PHP packages deployed in production
        # See https://github.com/fabpot/local-php-security-checker
        spec: '50 23 * * *'
        cmd: if [ "$PLATFORM_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE" = "production" ]; then croncape php-security-checker; fi

.platform/services.yaml:
# platform/services.yaml
postgresql: #servis adı
    type: postgresql:15
    disk: 1024

.platform/routes.yaml:
"https://{all}/": { type: upstream, upstream: "app:http" }
"http://{all}/": { type: redirect, to: "https://{all}/" }

When I connect to the platform with platform ssh command and try to see DATABASE_URL with echo $DATABASE_URL
I'm seeing result like this:
web@app.0:~$ echo $DATABASE_URL
postgresql://main:main@database.internal:5432/main?serverVersion=15&charset=utf8
Also I have created a file named .environment includes configuration for DATABASE_URL:

# Create your DATABASE_URL variable here

DATABASE_URL="postgresql://$DATABASE_USERNAME:$DATABASE_PASSWORD@$DATABASE_HOST:$DATABASE_PORT/$DATABASE_DATABASE?serverVersion=$DATABASE_VERSION&charset=utf8"
echo "Database configuration completed"
echo $DATABASE_URL

Also when I try to see $APP_ENV, I'm using result as "prod" but in .env file it adjusted as "production"
Also when I try to get data from database using API, I'm getting all data but if I try to post data into the database it returns that:

Error: response status is 500

Response body
{
"@id": "/api/errors",
"@type": "hydra:Error",
"title": "An error occurred",
"detail": "Internal Server Error",
"status": 500,
"type": "/errors/500",
"hydra:title": "An error occurred",
"hydra:description": "Internal Server Error"
}

Though it returns 500, the API posts the data to the database and I can see new data in resource with GET request.
Also I have seen some code in Platform.sh documentation to setting up the DATABASE_URL like this:

<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Platformsh\ConfigReader\Config;

// Create a new config object to ease reading the Platform.sh environment variables.
// You can alternatively use getenv() yourself.
$config = new Config();

// The 'database' relationship is generally the name of primary SQL database of an application.
// It could be anything, though, as in the case here here where it's called "postgresql".
$credentials = $config->credentials('postgresql');

try {
    // Connect to the database using PDO.  If using some other abstraction layer you would
    // inject the values from $database into whatever your abstraction layer asks for.
    $dsn = sprintf('pgsql:host=%s;port=%d;dbname=%s', $credentials['host'], $credentials['port'], $credentials['path']);
    $conn = new \PDO($dsn, $credentials['username'], $credentials['password'], [
        // Always use Exception error mode with PDO, as it's more reliable.
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    ]);

    $conn->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS People");

    // Creating a table.
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS People (
      id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
      name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
      city VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
      )";
    $conn->query($sql);

    // Insert data.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO People (name, city) VALUES
        ('Neil Armstrong', 'Moon'),
        ('Buzz Aldrin', 'Glen Ridge'),
        ('Sally Ride', 'La Jolla');";
    $conn->query($sql);

    // Show table.
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM People";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $result->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if ($result) {
        print <<<TABLE


NameCity


TABLE;
        foreach ($result as $record) {
            printf("%s%s\n", $record->name, $record->city);
        }
        print "\n\n";
    }

    // Drop table.
    $sql = "DROP TABLE People";
    $conn->query($sql);

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}

But I don't know where do I should add this file to the project
Anyone can control the files and show me my mistakes for configuration. Also please explain how the API platform works, how to see logs and errors during deployment and running.
I want to deploy project with correct way and configure the files. Also when I try to post the API should be returns 200 but in DELETE, POST operations it returns 500 error. Also can anyone explain how can I control the project during runnning on Platform.sh from command line.
Before I forgot this is the doctrine.yaml file:
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '15'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        enable_lazy_ghost_objects: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App

when@test:
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            # "TEST_TOKEN" is typically set by ParaTest
            dbname_suffix: '_test%env(default::TEST_TOKEN)%'

when@prod:
    doctrine:
        orm:
            auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
            proxy_dir: '%kernel.build_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies'
            query_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
            result_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool

    framework:
        cache:
            pools:
                doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.app
                doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.system

